# With SharePoint calculations, How can I do do a count on if one column is greater than X as well as another column being greater than Y?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I want to do the following with a SharePoint calculated field:
I have two columns that count results from other columns called Red and Amber.
IF Red is 4 or more fail otherwise pass, if red is 3 or more and amber is 2 or more fail otherwise pass, if red is 2 or more and amber is 3 or more fail otherwise pass.
I've tried the following and it did not work:

```
IF([Red]>3,"Fail","Pass")+IF(AND([Red]>2,[Amber]>1),"Fail","Pass")+IF(AND([Red]>1,[Amber]>2),"Fail","Pass")
```

It just gave me the result: #VALUE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
IF([Red]>3,"Fail",IF(AND([Red]>2,[Amber]>1),"Fail",IF(AND([Red]>1,[Amber]>2),"Fail","Pass")))
```